# Conditional checkbox

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, checkboxes, selection

[image]
I have a checkbox with two possible things underneath it.

If the box is not checked, there will be a dropdown with different default options.

If the box is checked, the user will have to assign two values themselves, via two textboxes.

What is the best way to show these two different methods?

Comment: do you have a rough mock on what you're working on so far?

Comment: just included image.Please advice

Comment: in first condition , if User un selected option 1 though, user able to select value. so it is loosely couple but value matter to do internal calculation.

Comment: so...does a user have to choose an option, or do they have an option for none selected?

Comment: I am not seeing two text boxes

Answer (score 2):

If you need clear indication of a choice, try radio buttons with the [expose within pattern](https://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2007/02/selection-dependent-inputs.php).

You'll see this in LukeW's **[Web Form Design](http://rosenfeldmedia.com/books/web-form-design/)** book.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fONbT6.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**Pro**

- User sees all available options
- User can see currently selected
- Data from previous selections can be persisted, so a user can go back to a previous selection at a later time (like a custom mix/max range)